Data is not populating in WPF Form
I am woking on a VSTO Excel Addin and on a button click i am opening a WPF form.
case 1 : I am working on a citrix environment and citrix opened on a single screen now i open excel and click on my ribbon button and my wpf form is working fine.
But when i drag my cirtix window from single monitor to dual monitor and my wpf form goes blank as present is screen shot.

case 1 : I am working on a citrix environment and citrix opened on a dual screen(on both the screens) now i open excel and click on my ribbon button and my wpf form is working fine.
But when i drag my cirtix window from dual monitor to single monitor and my wpf form goes blank same as above.
I am using show dialog for displaying WPF form.
var prepareViewForm = new WpfContainerForm(objPrepareView, (int)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Width, (int)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Height);
prepareViewForm.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
prepareViewForm.HideWindowBezel();

var result = prepareViewForm.ShowDialog();

I have tried changing properties
StartPosition from CenterParent to mannual.
Tried fixing the positions of the form but also not work.
How can i fix this problem?

Check your monitors display settings to be 100%

Both of my monitors has same resolution and both have 100% (scale and layout)

Try to reset the position after the issue occurred (blank) by a temporarily button, if it works plan to bind it to one of  the window events (sizechanged, ...)

I didn't get this can you explain further?

What I'm thinking of is, to create a temporarily button, and on its clickevent try to recalculte the position for example prepareViewForm.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterParent;, it it work then you can remove the temporarily button and bind the same action with onWindowSizeChanged event
